# Internationalization Android app with retrofit and a SLIM php api

Tags: php, android, api, internationalization, retrofit

I ask myself about how to handle the internationalization on my Android application. (I just want to handle the FR language and the EN language).

I have already managed an internationalized app but this time, all the content is on a MySQL database.

I have created a little API with PHP and SLIM framework and I use Retrofit on my android app to do request on the API.

My question is : how I can manage the language? I guess obviously I have to duplicate the content in my datatbase for the second language. But for getting the right content in my android app, how I can do it?

Maybe I can pass parameters on the header request with retrofit and filter on the API by language?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: I'd say that's what the `Accept-Language` Header is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@GET("/greeting")
void getInternationalizedGreeting(@Header("Accept-Language") String languagePreference, Callback<Greeting> callback)
```

Define `languagePreference` in a way your web server will understand, i.e. something like

```
da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7`
```

See also here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4.